# 2000 Honda Accord Stalls Starting in Hot Weather

Tags: honda, accord, idle, stall

I have a 2000 Honda Accord with approximately 300,000 KM (186400 Miles). It usually runs great except for a slowly dying B7XA transmission.

I've noticed when starting it in hot weather or if the engine is hot that it will sometimes stall out, by which I mean the engine turns over but it fails to idle properly so the tach needle just falls from ~2000 RPM to zero. When this happens the engine runs very roughly and I get P0300 (random misfire) and P030X (Cylinder X misfire for X being any and all cylinders) codes.

If I keep the RPMs up by applying the accelerator and placing the car in reverse or drive it will start to idle and drive just fine. It has never stalled during regular driving, only after a hot start.

I have replaced the battery and spark plugs within the last few months (unrelated) and also removed and resoldered the relays inside the main relay module. I've seen some other suggestions about the EGR valve, PCM or fuel regulator but since this condition occurs only during hot starts I'm not convinced about the PVM or fuel regulator being faulty.

Has anyone seen similar problems or have any advice for how to proceed?

**Edit**: After reading a bit more, I think this problem is related to "hot soak" and can be solved by swapping the fuel rails from a 2000 Honda Odyssey. [Here's a forum post](https://www.driveaccord.net/forums/53-6th-generation/493617-heat-soak-issue-its-potential-solution.html) describing this process in more detail.

Comment: You'd have to find out if it's an ignition, mechanical, or fuel related misfire. scan data covering the major pids would help. Does the IACV move when actuated? Does the solenoid work?

Comment: I haven't checked the Idle Air Control Valve (IAVC) valve but I will, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the fuel pump isn't able to get enough fuel into the cylinders. Could be a failing pump, clogged fuel filter, etc.

Comment: You could really improve this answer by stating how the OP could go about testing their fuel pump.

Comment: any idea why it would occur during a hot start and not any other time? I figure if it was the fuel pump it would happen regularly.